# Custom attribute filter for product listing not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to filter products using category and products with categorie and location but the filter not working here's my code

```
<?php
$ty=array(34,15);
foreach($ty as $categoryid) { 
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid); //My cat id is 10
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$prodCollection->addAttributeToSelect('name','product_location');
$prodCollection->addAttributeToFilter('product_location', array('like' => 'Bangalore, Karnataka, India'));
foreach ($prodCollection as $product) {
$prdIds[] = $product->getId(); ///Store all th eproduct id in $prdIds array
}
foreach($prdIds as $_prdIds){
$product_id = $_prdIds;
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id
$prdId1s[]=$_product;
}
$_productCollection = $prdId1s;
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think For `product_location` you are using `multiselect`, so you have to use `findset` in your code and in findset you have to pass `optionId` for every option not option value right now you have pass option value like `banglore,india` But you have to pass option Id in array With in fineset

Create array like below with optionId
`array(10,20,30)`

and after that your addAttributeToFilter Belike

```
->addFieldToFilter('product_location',
            array(
                array('finset'=> array(your array variable)),
                                )
        )
```

Comment: I am using custom box with text field user will search suppose Bangalore so if the value exists like  Bangalore  in product_location i need to show filters with that location